# MVC5/Bootstrap: adding to Nav doesn't push body content down

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap-3, navigation, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am working in VS2013 U4 with an MVC/bootstrap website and when I add to the nav/menu, it's not pushing everything down, the top of the body is getting cut off.
I have two sub-menus that show depending on what controller(s) the user's hitting. When they show up, it cuts the top off the page body.
Here's my _Layout that's pertinent:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("XXXX Corporate", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "AboutUs", "About")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Executives", "Section/Executive-Team", "Executive")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Portfolio", "Index", "Property")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Research", "Index", "ResearchArticle")</li>
            </ul>
            <p class="nav navbar-text navbar-right">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
        </div>
        @{ // Sub-Menu for About Sections
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Contains("About")
                || HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Contains("Executive"))
            {
                Html.RenderAction("AboutSubMenu", "About");
            }
        }

        @{ // Sub-Menu for Executive Sections
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Contains("Executive"))
            {
                Html.RenderAction("ExecutiveSubMenu", "Executive");
            }
        }           
    </div>
</div>
```

about submenu:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About Us", "AboutUs", "About", null, null)</li>
```

...

Here's what it looks like:
[image: How it looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, bootstrap's "navbar-fixed-top" means it's CSS position:fixed keeps it at the top and above everything else. So, what is needed is padding-top in the body like this:

```
 @{ // Sub-Menu for About Sections
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Contains("About")
                || HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Contains("Executive")
                || HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Contains("ResearchArticle"))
            {
                Html.RenderAction("AboutSubMenu", "About");
                // since this is a 'fixed' menu we need to set padding dynamically
                <style>
                    body {
                        padding-top: 90px;
                    }
                </style>
            }
        }

        @{ // Sub-Menu for Executive Sections
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Contains("Executive"))
            {
                Html.RenderAction("ExecutiveSubMenu", "Executive");
                // since this is a 'fixed' menu we need to set padding dynamically
                <style>
                    body {
                        padding-top: 140px;
                    }
                </style>
            }
        }
```

And of course, the last CSS placed overrides earlier CSS so, if the second menu shows (... browsing on the Executive controller) it will move everything down further.